# Why did the "drive to the hospital" scene abruptly switch from day to night?

Tags: plot-explanation, continuity, malignant

In *Malignant* (2021), we see Sydney drive to the abandoned hospital to collect evidence, and there is a shot of the building in broad daylight, perhaps a few kilometers away. She even reacts to seeing the hospital. But then it switches to the car pulling up at night, so what happened? It's impossible for the sun to set that quickly.

In other words, is this an unintended continuity error, a plot hole, or intentional?

Comment: It's so frequent a situation that i'm pretty sure it's a trope by itself

Comment: Makes me think of Plan 9 from Outer Space, where they went back & forth from day to night many times in a single scene. Noteworthy as the worst movie ever made & featured in Tim Burton's [Ed Wood](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109707/)

Comment: More seriously, but still not an answer… sometimes this disparity can be because of the latitude of the setting, the director's home or birthplace, or that of the audience. I am ever-surprised when in California or Tenerife how the sun seems to fall over the horizon like a dropped basketball. Where I live normally, 'sunset' can last an hour or more in summer.